# Forward https client's header to backend application

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, proxy, forward

I'm using nginx like reverse proxy to backend application.
- The clients connects to nginx with certificate-A.pem, and nginx use an intermediate CA chained with the root CA to validate the clients (ALL OK).

Now come the problem:
- nginx must forward the requests to the backend application using the same header used by the real host (containing the certificate-A.pem). The packets forwarded to the backend application must be identical to the clients packets recived by nginx.

Why? Because i've a very large number of clients to manage (every one with a different certificate issued by the same Intermediate CA), the backend need the certificate (used to do stuff) but i want to pre-verify this certificate with nginx (really fastest)

I've tired different configuration, but i can't figure how to proxy_set the correct header

```
upstream proxy_server {
 server     127.0.0.1:8443;  <---my backend application
}

server {
listen   443 ssl;
listen   [::]:443;

ssl_certificate   /home/mender/Projects/utility-scripts/gwsw-root-gen/cert_tree/intermediate_CA/gwsw/x509-med_ca_gwsw.pem;

ssl_certificate_key   /home/mender/Projects/utility-scripts/gwsw-root-gen/cert_tree/intermediate_CA/gwsw/x509-med_ca_gwsw-key.pem;

location / {
proxy_pass   https://proxy_server;
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Custom-Referrer $http_x_custom_referrer;
   }
}
```

Cannot verificate the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The packets forwarded to the backend application must be identical to the clients packets recived by nginx.

If this is the case, I believe you need to just use nginx in `stream` mode acting as a TCP proxy. I don't know that you'd be able to do any validation on the `nginx` side however, it'll be purely be up to the backend application.

Its not possible (I don't think) to both have `nginx` set up an SSL connection and *also* pass the encrypted data to the backend.

Comment: My last working configuration have the stream module and the ssl_preread and it's work,but i need to pre-check the request....I think the only solution (bad and slow) is to re-encrypt the packet (by nginx)....i need to change the architecture